Circling aircraft
Hi guys I'm a newbie here, so apologise if this has already been answered. I'm in The UK and since 2020 RAF aircraft have been circling my city, and have noticed after that it is happening in other parts of UK. They are quite often Eurofighter Typhoons. I'm not talking refuelling patterns, circles or variations of directly above the city. I'm seeing them on radar websites, which I understand can be iffy, but I can very much hear and often see them, so they are determinedly covering the area. This has involved numbers of them, I've seen 7 listed on radar with individual call signs, and sometimes multiple times a day. As it's mainland UK can't see why it would be surveillance, radar, or command and control. I've considered backup for coastal rescue, but it happens far too frequently, and I've seen similar activity over inland settlements. I would think it is also a bit weird for training to have close proximity multiple aircraft to buzz over a city. Also, the same aircraft can stay up to about half hour so suggest that's a bit long for waypoint behaviour. Thank you for any input as it's confusing me now.

Unless you provide a screenshot of a tracking site, or a registration number which points to a specific example, it is not possible to answer, only to provide opinions which is not helpful.

How do fighter pilots maintain their edge? How do they stay "good"?
Practice practice practice. Those are not on operational missions, just practice.
Having a good aircraft is only part of the equation. The pilot must also be good.
I see the same here over coastal Virginia (USA). Or, on FR24, over Kansas City. Or near Las Vegas.
Or these guys near Tuscon AZ, on a quiet Thursday morning.

(from FlightRadar24)

Hi, thank you for your reply. That is the pretty much one of the few conclusions I can come to, but I'm not sure why they stay over the city for sometimes up to half hour.

Maybe, @YorkshireRover, they're practicing spotting ground targets within a city. It's easy to pick out a city from the countryside, but it's harder to pick out Bob's Munitions Factory when it's sitting next to Annie's Pretzles & Pickles. Learning to spot ground targets from the air is good, even with all the high tech gizmos on today's fighter aircraft.

@FreeMan Thank you for taking the time to respond, and that sounds like the most likely answer to me.
